# new Date().getTimezoneOffset() returns the wrong time zone

Tags: javascript

I am in Israel, so my offset right now should be `120`. Yet, when I use `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()`, I get back `-120`, so not just a daylight savings issue.
Should I simply change every minus to plus and vice versa? I don't know what might be the case for users in other timezones.

That's my function:

```
  firebase
    .database()
    .ref("words/" + newPostKey)
    .set({
      word,
      length: word.length,
      time_to_action: timeToAction,
      output: output,
      lang: project.lang,
      country: project.country,
      user: userUID,
      timestamp : Date.now(),
      timezone_offset : new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
    });
```

and `timezone_offset` is what gets saved as `-120`. I am in Tel Aviv.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset _“returns the time zone difference, in minutes, **from** current locale (host system settings) **to** UTC”_ - _“I am in Israel, so my offset right now should be 120”_ - that is simply the other direction, _from_ UTC _to_ your locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getTimezoneOffset()` is working well. This function retuns the number of minutes you have to add to your current time to get the UTC time, so in GMT+X the result is negative.

Comment: Oh gotcha!! Thank you, will accept this answer as soon as a it lets me.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I live in Ukraine and even if we have (UTC + 02: 00) now we are ahead of UTC by 3 hours cause we have 'winter time', when clocks are set back by one hour. So `new Date().GetTimezoneOffset()` returned `'-120'`, while `new Date(0).getTimezoneOffset()` returned `'-180'`. Maybe that's the case you faced with.

Comment: Did you solve it? It is -180 today although it should be -120 - winter time ended 6 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are ahead of GMT by 2 hours therefor to get back to GMT you have to subtract 120 minutes. Your offset is -120.